# pymeshlab's function "meshing_decimation_quadric_edge_collapse" replacement in open3d

Tags: open3d, pymeshlab

Thanks for your help in advance

I am new to 3D.
I am trying to implement open3d to replace pymeshlab.

Even going through several documents I could not come up with a relacement of the function from pymeshlab "meshing_decimation_quadric_edge_collapse".

I am curious if "open3d.geometry.simplify_quadric_decimation(input, target_number_of_triangles)" could replace that function.

Could someone help me out with this?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be the same decimation algorithm (based on [QSLIM](http://mgarland.org/software/qslim.html), by Garland and Heckbert) but with less options that the implementation given in meshlab, so you can't write a complete replacement.

For example, one interesting option in meshlab is "Preserve boundary", which allows to split a mesh in two halves and decimate only one half ensuring that the boundaries will still match and you can merge the result, or the "planar simplification"
For example in [medusa-rondanini](https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/the-medusa-rondanini-78c664b9e59b454babaecd8389c514ff) model by Cosmowenman, where the bak of the model has been agressively decimated.

Almost every casual user won't notice the difference between both implementations of the algorithm, but professional users will probably stick to meshlab.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explaination!